# result by AJAX not adoptable

Tags: ajax, yii2

The following code will give me all records using AJAX request as intended. Unfortunately, I am not able to take one selected record into form. I just can select them, not take them. I assume some error in `templateResult` or `templateSelection`.

**Rephrasing question**: not take them means, that I am not able to adopt one single record being displayed into form. It's like food for a dog which can't be eaten by the dog, ' cause hand will be moved away again and again... Hope this helped to understand my question. P.S.:`id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1` is Property of model

Here is the code of the view:

```
$url = \yii\helpers\Url::to ( [ 'berufe' ] );
    ?><?=
    $form->field ( $model , 'id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1' , [ 'addon' => [
            'prepend' => [ 'content' => 'gelernter Beruf 1' ] ] ] )->widget ( \kartik\widgets\Select2::classname () , [
        'options' => [ 'placeholder' => 'Berufe suchen ...' ] ,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true ,
            'minimumInputLength' => 3 ,
            'language' => [
                'errorLoading' => new JsExpression ( "function () { return 'Waiting for results...'; }" ) ,
            ] ,
            'ajax' => [
                'url' => $url ,
                'dataType' => 'json' ,
                'data' => new JsExpression ( 'function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }' )
            ] ,
            'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression ( 'function (markup) { return markup; }' ) ,
            'templateResult' => new JsExpression ( 'function(berufe) { return berufe.text; }' ) ,
            'templateSelection' => new JsExpression ( 'function (berufe) { return berufe.text; }' ) ,
        ] ,
    ] )->label ( false );
```

Here is controller code which works pretty fine:

```
public function actionBerufe( $q = null , $id = null ) {
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $out = [ 'results' => [ 'id' => '' , 'text' => '' ] ];
    if ( !is_null ( $q ) ) {
        $query = new \yii\db\Query();
        $query->select ( 'ID, Bezeichnung_neutral_kurz  AS text' )
                ->from ( 'yii2_ba.ba_berufe' )
                ->where ( [ 'like' , 'Bezeichnung_neutral_kurz' , $q ] )
                ->limit ( 20 );
        $command = $query->createCommand ();
        $data = $command->queryAll ();
        $out['results'] = array_values ( $data );
    } elseif ( $id > 0 ) {
        $out['results'] = [ 'id' => $id , 'text' => \common\modules\basis\models\BaBerufe::find ( $id )->Bezeichnung_neutral_kurz ];
    }
    return $out;
}
```

**Rephrasing question**:

```
     'templateResult' => new JsExpression ( 'function (berufe) { return console.log(berufe); berufe.text; }' ) ,
```

will give me id and properties like this:

```
Object { ID: "72", text: "\"Absatzfachkraft\"" }
Object { ID: "287", text: "\"Akustikfacharbeiter/in\"" }
```

**but**

```
     'templateSelection' => new JsExpression ( 'function (berufe) { return console.log(berufe); berufe.text; }' ) ,
```

will give me following output:

```
Object { id: "", text: "Berufe suchen ..." }
Object { id: "", text: "Berufe suchen ..." }
```

Hope this helps nicolascolman to fix problem...

Comment: are you trying to display all the records in a dropdown and on selecting you want the whole form to be populated with the relevant columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1 is an object. Try this:

```
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression ( 'function (id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1) { return console.log(id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1); id_ba_xml_gelernter_beruf_1.text; }' ) ,
```

You will see an object in the console with ID and text properties. 
Then, replace the console.log(...) with your code.

Comment: I only will get id and properties for 'templateResult', for 'templateSelection', I will get Object { id: "", text: "Berufe suchen ..." }

Comment: See rephrasing question

Comment: Are you geting more tan item in the array? If so, try changing ID for id in your query.

Comment: How to change id. Maybe like this:      $query->select ( 'ID AS bez, Bezeichnung_neutral_kurz  AS text' )
                ->from ( 'yii2_ba.ba_berufe' )
                ->where ( [ 'like' , 'Bezeichnung_neutral_kurz' , $q ] )
                ->limit ( 20 );

Comment: Great Job. Problem got solved using alias for ID. Thx a lot. Gave bu reputation points for ur efforts!

Comment: Great Job. Problem got solved using alias id for ID. Thx a lot!! Gave U(nicolascolman) reputation points for ur efforts!